# calling javascript from js file

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have elements on my parent page that changes only if hidden iframe within contain one div id.

Everything is fine if I let code on html page :

```
 <iframe id="myiframe" style="display:none" onload="load()" name="myiframe"   src="mysite.com"></iframe>
```

JavaScript:

```
function load(){


if (window.frames[0].document.getElementById('applications'))
{
var str=document.getElementById("tst").innerHTML;
var n=str.replace("Login","Logout");}}
document.getElementById('tst').href='logout';
```

But I need iframe code deleted from html file and relocated js file.

I use this code in js file to trigger iframe:

```
window.onload = function(){
var link = "iframelink"
 var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.frameBorder=0;
iframe.width="300px";
iframe.height="250px";
iframe.id="randomid";
iframe.addEventListener("load", load);
iframe.setAttribute("src", link);
document.getElementById("ad54").appendChild(iframe);
}
```

html code to get iframe:

```
<div id="ad54"</div>
```

Iframe launches, but right now I get no elements changed on parent page although iframe is triggered . When iframe is loaded I need those changes to take place in parent page.

Comment: Are both pages (parent and iframe) on the same domain?

Comment: Yes , on the same domain. Iframe closed :)

Comment: Im a little confused with what you are trying to achieve. You have load() called twice, once for the iframe and also for the div (which isnt supported by the way)

Comment: If div id 'applications' is found on iframe within parent page, then we change 'Login' in 'Logout' on parent page. I remove it onload="load()" from div, added iframe.addEventListener("load", load) on js file; but still no changes.

Answer (score 1):

`<div>` elements do not load external content, so they never fire `load` events.

You appear to be trying to fire the event when the `iframe` content loads. You need to attach your event listener to the iframe.

```
iframe.addEventListener("load", load);
iframe.setAttribute("src", link);
```